# How to iterate through nested dict in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of 2 dictionaries which contain 3 dictionaries and I need to create a list with the key `base` or any other key inside the 3 dictionaries. The end result would be something like this:

```
>>> bases[0]
['BCH', 'BCH', 'BCC']

>>> bases[1]
['ZEC', 'ZRX', 'ZAC']
```

This is how my list looks like :

```
>>> markets_details
{
    'BCH/BTC': {
        'active': True,
        'altname': 'BCHXBT',
        'base': 'BCH',   
        'darkpool': False
    },
    'BCH/EUR': {
        'active': True,
        'altname': 'BCHEUR',
        'base': 'BCH',
        'darkpool': False
    },
    'BCC/EUR': {
        'active': True,
        'altname': 'BCCEUR',
        'base': 'BCC',
        'darkpool': False
    }
},{
    'ZEC/BTC': {
        'active': True,
        'altname': 'ZECXBT',
        'base': 'ZEC',
        'darkpool': False
    },
    'ZRX/EUR': {
        'active': True,
        'altname': 'ZRXEUR',
        'base': 'ZRX',
        'darkpool': False
    },
    'ZAC/EUR': {
        'active': True,
        'altname': 'ZACEUR',
        'base': 'ZAC',
        'darkpool': False
    }
}
```

I'm able to create a list of symbols with :

```
>>> symbols = [list(m.keys()) for m in markets_details]
```

But I can't create a list with the key `base`. To me this is supposed to work, what am'I doing wrong ?

```
>>> bases = [m[k for k in list(m.keys())]['base'] for m in markets_details]
```

For every exchange `m` I create a list of symbols with `list(m.keys())`, select each symbol `k` then access the `[base]` key.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to work out the logic for yourself is to construct a long-form nested `for` loop:

```
res = []
for d1 in markets_details:
    for _, d2 in d1.items():
        for k, v in d2.items():
            if k == 'base':
                res.append(v)

print(res)

['BCH', 'BCH', 'BCC', 'ZEC', 'ZRX', 'ZAC']
```

Having done this, you can then write the logic for your equivalent list comprehension:

```
res = [sub_dict['base'] for d in markets_details for sub_dict in d.values()]
```

If you need to identify which dictionary results originate from, you can restructure your list comprehension to include a nested list:

```
res = [[sub_dict['base'] for sub_dict in d.values()] for d in markets_details]

print(res)

[['BCH', 'BCH', 'BCC'], ['ZEC', 'ZRX', 'ZAC']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

A solution without the `split` would be:

```
[[pair['base'] for pair in market.values()] for market in markets_details]
```

Comment: It's good practice to iterate dictionary values explicitly, e.g. `[v for v in d.values()]` rather than `[d[k] for k in d]`. It's also more efficient and (arguably) more readable.